# Reducing A'B+(ABC)'+C(B'+A) with boolean algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, boolean

what is the possible way to reduce this equation with Boolean algebra to smallest number of terms

```
A'B+(ABC)'+C(B'+A)
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all try to ask question in more organized way
second, make sure you know elements of boolean algebra this can be reduced with DeMorgan rule

apply DeMorgan rule

```
A'B=A+B'
(ABC)'=A'+B'+C'
C(B'+A)=C'+(A+B')'
```

then

```
A'B+(ABC)'+C(B'+A)=(A+B')+A'+B'+C'+C'+(A+B')'
```

let `x=(A+B')`

```
A'B+(ABC)'+C(B'+A)=X+A'+B'+C'+C'+X'
X + X' =1
```

finally

```
A'B+(ABC)'+C(B'+A)=A'+B'+C'+C'=A'+B'+C'
```

final result is

```
A'+B'+C'
```